# Generador de colores vivos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, algoritmos, color

Estoy creando gráficos pastel con chart.js, al momento de crear el gráfico genero colores aleatorios con la siguiente función:

```
getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Sin embargo esta genera el color sin ningún tipo de filtro, quiero generar únicamente colores vivos, evitando grises, negros o apagados, ¿como los podría filtrar o mejorar la función existente?

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    var str = "<div style='background-color:"+color+"'><button id='b1'>hola</button></div>"
    document.write(str);
    return color;
}
console.log(getRandomColor());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener colores vivos y brillantes para pintar a las gráficas podemos basarnos en los siguientes hechos:

El espectro de colores brillantes es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los colores en este espectro se caracterizan por que en su composición, uno de los 3 colores primarios esta en su valor máximo (FF), otro al minimo (00) y el otro varia entre el mínimo y el máximo valor.

Por tanto el codigo HTML de un color vivo se puede representar como la permutación de 3 caracteres (FF, 00 y otro aleatorio).

Para simular estas permutaciones podemos establecer el array de caracteres de la siguiente forma:

```
var num=(Math.floor(Math.random()*4)*4).toString(16);
var letters = ['0','F',num];
```

se puede usar '0' y 'F' en lugar de '00' y 'FF' ya que un color HTML también se puede representar con 3 caracteres, luego el valor de `num` variara entre 0,4,8 y C hexadecimal (se hace esta separación para que exista mas contraste entre los colores).

Luego obtenemos la permutación extraendo un carácter del array de forma aleatoria para agregarlo a la cadena `color`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    let pos=Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
    color += letters[pos];
    letters.splice(pos,1);
}
```

Podemos almacenar los colores que ya se han usado en un *array* para evitar que se repitan con las siguientes lineas:

```
if(colores.includes(color))
      return getRandomColor();
    else
      colores.push(color)
```

De ese modo el código queda de la siguiente forma, en este ejemplo se generan 20 colores vivos distintos de forma aleatoria:

```js
var colores=[];

function getRandomColor() {
    var num=(Math.floor(Math.random()*4)*4).toString(16);
    var letters = ['0','F',num];
    var color = '#';
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        let pos=Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
        color += letters[pos];
        letters.splice(pos,1);
    }
    
    //para evitar que se repitan colores 
    if(colores.includes(color))
      return getRandomColor();
    else
      colores.push(color)
      
    var str = "<div style='background-color:"+color+"'><button id='b1'>hola</button></div>"
    document.getElementById('colores').innerHTML+=str;
    return color;
}

for(i=0;i<20;i++)
  console.log(getRandomColor());
```

```html
<div id="colores">
  
</div>
```

Y de esa forma se pueden generar colores llamativos evitando colores apagados, grises, blancos y negros, saludos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 2):

**SE ME OCURRE OTRA SOLUCION:** Usando la generacion de numero hexadecimales veo dificil tratar de filtar mediante una regla que genere colores pasteles o claros.

La otra forma de solucionar el problema es usando la generacion de colores por **RGB** aqui se puede hacer un generador aleatorio individual para los tres canales y limitar el rango del numero generado por los valores altos y bajos (entre 120 a 240) para evitar los colores oscuros.

**Aqui te adjunto el  nuevo codigo:**

al pulsar el boton de poner color clona un nuevo div y genera otro color, el div clonado tiene title para identificar su color `rgb()`

```html
       <button onclick="colorear();">Poner Color</button>
        <br>
        <div class="bloquediv" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; float: left; background-color: red; margin:  5px;"></div>
        <div id="historico"></div>
    <script>
        // funcion para generar colores aleatorios
        function getRandomColor(minR,maxR,minG,maxG,minB,maxB) {
            // generar rango aleatorio por RGB con min y max de valore
            colorR=Math.floor(Math.random() * maxR) + minR;
            colorG=Math.floor(Math.random() * maxG) + minG;
            colorB=Math.floor(Math.random() * maxB) + minB;
            var color ='';
            // armar sintaxi rgb
            color = color.concat('rgb(',colorR,',',colorG,',',colorB,')');
            return color;
        }

        // funcion para probar clores en cajon DIV;
        function colorear() {
            color = getRandomColor(120,240,120,240,120,240);
            console.log(color);
            document.getElementsByClassName("bloquediv")[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
            document.getElementsByClassName("bloquediv")[0].setAttribute('title', color);

            var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("bloquediv")[0];
            var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById("historico").appendChild(cln);
        }
        
    </script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Los colores grises tiene la caracterisitica que tienen el mismo valor en los 3 canales RGB, por ejemplo

```js
function getRandomColor(r,g,b) {
    var str = "<div style='background-color: #"+r+g+b+"'><button id='b1'>hola</button></div>"
    document.write(str);
    return str;
}
getRandomColor('a', 'a', 'a');
getRandomColor('2', '2', '2');
getRandomColor('6', '6', '6');
```

Los colores negros se obtienen cuando los 3 canales tienen valores cercanos al cero y los colores blancos cuando los valores son cercanos al 255.

En tu caso, los valores son hexadecimales, asi que los canales los dividimos en valores que van del #000000(negro) al #FFFFFF(blanco), cada par de valores corresponde a un canal, sin embargo podemos trabajar con valores de un #000 al #FFF, que es una forma casi equivalente aunque con un numero reducido de posibilidades(combinaciones).

Ahora solo debemos evitar que los 3 canales sean iguales o cercanos al blanco o al negro:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
      if (i==2){
        var lastcolor = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        if ( color.search(lastcolor) >= 0 ){
          color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }else{
          i--;
        }
      }
      else{
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
    }
    var str = "<div style='background-color:"+color+"'><button id='b1'>hola</button></div>"
    document.write(str);
    return color;
}
console.log(getRandomColor());
```

Solo hago la comparación en el ultimo valor porque no importa si hay dos canales iguales, solo importa que los 3 no sean iguales, así que solo hay que evitar que el tercero ya halla sido repetido.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la respuesta debería ir en la dirección de utilizar la representación HSV en lugar de la RGB.

En HSV un color se identifica por tres números, cada uno de ellos entre 0 y 1, siendo el primero el "hue" (el "tono", o lo que simplemente llamaríamos "color", que es lo que diferencia un rojo de un verde, por ejemplo), el segundo la saturación (cuanto más alta más "puro" es ese color, y cuanto más baja, más se mezcla con blanco y se vuelve más "pastel", llegando a ser gris en saturaciones bajas) y el tercero es el valor, o luminosidad (si se acerca a 0 tira al negro, y si se acerca a 1, al correspondiente color).

Usando este esquema, consigues colores "vivos" sin más que poner 1 en la saturación y 1 en el valor. Jugando con diferentes valores para el "hue", consigues los diferentes colores, y todos serían "vivos". Si los quieres más "pastel", cambia la saturación a 0.5 por ejemplo.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de una función que convierte del modelo HSV al RGB y de un bucle que itera por diferentes "hue" para generar los diferentes colores. Los imprime en hexadecimal por la consola y de paso los pinta en un canvas para que los veas.

```js
function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
  var r, g, b;

  var i = Math.floor(h * 6);
  var f = h * 6 - i;
  var p = v * (1 - s);
  var q = v * (1 - f * s);
  var t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);

  switch (i % 6) {
    case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
    case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
    case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
    case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
    case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
    case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
  }

  return [ r * 255, g * 255, b * 255 ];
}

function rgbToHex(c) {
  const r=Math.round(c[0]);
  const g=Math.round(c[1]);
  const b=Math.round(c[2]);
  return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

for (var h=0;h<=1;h+=0.01) {
   const color = rgbToHex(hsvToRgb(h, 1, 1));
   console.log(color);
   ctx.fillStyle = color;
   ctx.fillRect(h*500, 0, (h+0.01)*500, 100);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500></canvas>
```